# How to re-render static block from a dynamic block

Tags: php, wordpress, gutenberg-blocks

I need my gutenberg wordpress dynamic block to render all paragraph blocks in the page without saving it to the database.

```
<?php
function create_block_init()
{
    register_block_type(__DIR__ . '/build',
        array(
            'render_callback' => 'render_my_widget'
        ));

}

function replaceTextInParagraphs($newValToSet)
{
    $post = get_post();
    $content = $post->post_content;
    if (has_blocks($content)) {
        $blocks = parse_blocks($content);
        for ($i = 0; $i <= count($blocks); $i++) {
            $block = $blocks[$i];
            if ($block['blockName'] === "core/paragraph") {
                if (!empty($block['innerHTML'])) {
                    $block['innerHTML'] = str_replace("foo", $newValToSet, $block['innerHTML']);
                }
                if (!empty($block['innerContent']) && is_array($block['innerContent'])) {
                    $block['innerContent'] = array_map(function ($item) use ($newValToSet) {
                        return str_replace("foo", $newValToSet, $item['innerHTML']);
                    }, $block['innerContent']);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return $content;

}

function render_my_widget($attributes, $content)
{
    $newValToSet = $attributes['newVal'];
    $newContent = replaceTextInParagraphs($newValToSet);
    // How do i re render the content of the post???
}
```

I want basically replace some text in the paragraphs based on the current widget attribute. I am new to wordpress and not sure that what i am doing is the best option to achieve it. Also the example is simplified version. I need this block to be dynamic (it relies on URL passed params).
**The question is how to re-write static block html without saving it to the database, after i replaced the text?**
Hope it make sense.
thanks.